# Multi select Person field in search core results web part

Tags: 2007, search-results

I have a Person or group column that allows multiple selections.  I am displaying this field in a search results web part via a managed property.

Where multiple selections have been made, names after the first selection are displaying in the format #{UserID};#{Display Name} rather than just {Display Name}.

Could anyone point me towards the best way to just return the display name for all selections?

Many thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan, You can use the XSL to parse the result and split on the ;# to just return the Display Name for each user. Try the substring-after operator.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I'd started off down that path and wasn't getting anywhere but I was using the replace function with a regular expression and have just realised that's not available in 2007 (and XSLT 1.0).  Will go back and have another look.  Thanks again. Dan